# INSERT INTO statement after CASE WHEN in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

A table named ROUTINE r does have the following attributes: ID (NUMBER), NAME (VARCHAR2(40)), MONDAY_YN (NUMBER(1,0)), TUESDAY_YN (NUMBER(1,0)),..., SUNDAY_YN (NUMBER(1,0)), in which each routine has an ID, a name and also a representation of weekdays it is outstanding (e.g. MONDAY_YN=1) or not (MONDAY_YN=0). Additionally to check if a routine is successfully done on a specific date, there is a second table named ROUTINE_CHECKLIST rc that consists of the routine ID (Foreign key connection with table ROUTINE r), a date and a status (0 for outstanding, 1 for done).

Now, I want to insert data into the table ROUTINE_CHECKLIST with following SQL which works perfectly fine to insert the next 3 mondays for a specified Routine.

```
insert into EBA_MTGMIN_ROUTINE_CHECKLIST (ROUTINE_ID, routine_date, done_yn)
select ID, next_day ( sysdate, 'monday' ) + ( ( level - 1 ) * 7 ), 0
from EBA_MTGMIN_ROUTINE r
where r.ID = 4711
connect by level <= 3;
```

Depending on each weekday attribute in table ROUTINE a case statement should be used, that checks if r.MONDAY_YN = 1 then insert the next 3 mondays, if r.TUESDAY_YN = 1 then insert next 3 tuesdays, etc. To match these requirements I tried to make use of the SELECT CASE WHEN clause in the SQL statement as follows:

```
SELECT ro.MONDAY_YN,  
SELECT CASE WHEN ro.MONDAY_YN=1 THEN (insert into EBA_MTGMIN_ROUTINE_CHECKLIST (routine_date, done_yn, ROUTINE_ID)
select distinct next_day ( sysdate, 'monday' ) + ( ( level - 1 ) * 7 ), 0, r.ID
from EBA_MTGMIN_ROUTINE r
where r.ID = 4711
connect by level <= 3)
END
from EBA_MTGMIN_ROUTINE ro
where ro.ID = 4711;
```

That statement does not execute as expected, but results in ORA-00936: missing expression error. What would be an elegent way to extend the insert statement in Oracle SQL or PL/SQL to fill the table ROUTINE_CHECKLIST?

Comment: Which version of oracle are you using ? and is `EBA_MTGMIN_ROUTINE.ID` the primary key for the table ?

Comment: Yes EBA_MTGMIN_ROUTINE.ID is primary key and I am currently using ORACLE DB 11g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood for one record in the `routine` table there could be `monday_yn = 1` and `tuesday_yn = 1` or may be all and then we need to check for each day and insert next 3 days for the same day to the `checklist` table. I have come up with leveraging `insert all` statement where we can fire multiple insert statement using one source and conditions over it,

```
insert all
when monday_yn = 1 then
into eba_mtgmin_routine_checklist
 (routine_id, routine_date, done_yn)
values
 (routine_id,date_mon,0)
when tuesday_yn = 1 then
into eba_mtgmin_routine_checklist
 (routine_id, routine_date, done_yn)
values
 (routine_id,date_tue,0)
when sunday_yn = 1 then
into eba_mtgmin_routine_checklist
 (routine_id, routine_date, done_yn)
values
 (routine_id,date_sun,0)
 
select next_day(sysdate, 'monday')  + ((level - 1) * 7) date_mon
      ,next_day(sysdate, 'tuesday') + ((level - 1) * 7) date_tue
      ,next_day(sysdate, 'sunday')  + ((level - 1) * 7) date_sun
      , 0 done_yn
      , r.id routine_id
      , monday_yn
      , tuesday_yn
      , sunday_yn
  from eba_mtgmin_routine r
 where r.id = 4711
connect by level <= 3;
```

Demo can be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fbfc902d86453e146b0f340b349df542)

EDIT: Updated answer as asked by OP

```
insert all
when monday_yn = 1 then
into eba_mtgmin_routine_checklist
 (routine_id, routine_date, done_yn)
values
 (routine_id,date_mon,0)
when tuesday_yn = 1 then
into eba_mtgmin_routine_checklist
 (routine_id, routine_date, done_yn)
values
 (routine_id,date_tue,0)
when sunday_yn = 1 then
into eba_mtgmin_routine_checklist
 (routine_id, routine_date, done_yn)
values
 (routine_id,date_sun,0)
select next_day(sysdate, 'monday') + 
      ((lvl - 1) * 7) date_mon
      ,next_day(sysdate, 'tuesday') + 
      ((lvl - 1) * 7) date_tue
      ,next_day(sysdate, 'sunday') + 
      ((lvl - 1) * 7) date_sun
      , 0 done_yn
      , a.id routine_id
      , a.monday_yn
      , a.tuesday_yn
      , a.sunday_yn
  from
     ( select id, monday_yn, tuesday_yn, sunday_yn 
         from eba_mtgmin_routine r) a,
     (select level lvl
        from dual
      connect by level <= 3) b
```

You can verify in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=956ed5a61e95b9feb65ebacc564becad)

Comment: This insert all statement is really beautiful! Thank you very much. Is there a simple way to loop the statement in SQL in so far that the statement does iterate through all existing IDs?

Comment: Yes I think so. I have updated the answer. Please check if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, perhaps something like this might be what you're looking for.

```
insert into eba_mtgmin_routine_checklist
  (routine_date, done_yn, routine_id)
  (select *
   from (select distinct next_day(sysdate, 'monday') + (level - 1) * 7 routine_date,
                         0 done_yn, 
                         r.id routine_id
         from eba_mtgmin_routine r
         where r.id = 4711
         connect by level <= 3
        )
   where 1 = (select ro.monday_yn
              from eba_mtgmin_routine ro
              where ro.id = 4711
             )
  );
```